# Array Error (Incomplete type is not allowed)

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

I have an error with this line:

```
int arr[];
```

Error: Incomplete type is not allowed.

Main:

```
int i = 0;
int arr[];

AddToArray(node, arr, i);
```

Function AddToArray:

```
int AddToArray(Node *node, int arr[], int i){

if (node == NULL)
    return i;

arr[i] = maxRes(score);
i++;

return i;
}
```

What do I need to change so that I can call the AddToArray function to add new elements (values from a Binary Search Tree) to the array? The size of the array is the number of nodes in the BST. How do I get around this?

Comment: you need to specify a size for the array

Comment: Or use a `std::vector<int>` instead

Comment: did you want `int arr*;`? Please use `std::vector<int>` for dynamic arrays...

Comment: That is an error.  What are you trying to do?  What are you asking here?

Comment: What do I need to change so that I can call the AddToArray function to add new elements (values from a Binary Search Tree) to the array? The size of the array is the number of nodes in the BST. How do I get around this?

Comment: @Scrub c arrays cannot "grow on demand". You must use a container, such as `std::vector`.

Comment: An array has a fixed size.  You are getting your error because you have left out the size.  See [examples of how to declare an array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array).  That said, an array is probably the wrong container choice if you want to add elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what needs to be changed:

```
std::vector<int> arr;

AddToArray(node, arr);

void AddToArray(Node *node, std::vector<int>& arr) {

    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    arr.push_back(maxRes(score)); // what score?
}
```

Comment: On a side note, OP should learn the difference between an `array` and `std::vector` and WHY this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must state a specific size for an array that is static. If you do not wish to specify size, make the array dynamic or use a vector.

Seeing that you are using nodes and the function is adding to the array, I suggest you initialized the array with some constant max value.

If you wish to continue using static, this is what you should do.

For example:

```
const int MAX = 30;
int arr[MAX];
```

This should work.

Comment: This solution scares me a bit, because it resembles the kind of code that _looks like it works_, and then at some unspecified time in the future, it suddenly _stops working_.

Comment: @DrewDormann definitely not the suggested code to use for binary trees and nodes, however I attempted to format the code style with a static array since that is what they used. However this does work. It's just not a great idea to use static arrays in this type of code.